# WPF main.windows.xaml and app.xaml did not show

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, app.xaml

Me and my friends new to coding. We open Wpf project and via github i dowloands my pc. I look some tutorials and see that our project don't have main.windows.xaml and app.xaml ( picture 1 ). When i open new WPF project i can see they are here (Picture 2 ) How can i bring main.windows.xaml and app.xaml? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUDAb.png).
** Expecting to add our project to main.windows.xaml and app.xaml.**

Copy:Hello. Me and my friends new to coding. We open Wpf project and via github i dowloands my pc. I look some tutorials and see that our project don't have main.windows.xaml and app.xaml ( picture 1 ). When i open new WPF project i can see they are here (Picture 2 ) How can i bring main.windows.xaml and app.xaml? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUDAb.png).
** Expecting to add our project to main.windows.xaml and app.xaml.**

Answer (score 0):

Your **second picture** shows a WPF project correctly initialized which provides both the App.xaml/App.xaml.cs and the MainWindow.xaml/MainWindow.xaml.cs files.

Your **first picture** probably shows, instead, a [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/overview/?view=netdesktop-8.0) project. Forms was the precursor of WPF and, despite some similarities, is a different framework.

If you need to work on a Forms project, you will not have any App or MainWindow like in WPF. If, instead, you need to work with WPF be sure to initialize the project correctly from Visual Studio and then push it to GitHub. At that point you will have the desider files as in your second picture.